# Custom grid layout for woocommerce products

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Does anyone has any idea on how to show woocommerce shop page like the attached image? Black squares are products.

Thanks!

[image: Grid Layout]

Comment: We have an idea, but what have you tried?

Comment: I have tried with css grid-column and grid- row, targeting li child elements. Almost there!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@bragDeal this appears to be working for me:

```
ul.products.columns-3 li:nth-child(1){
     grid-column: 1 / 4;
     grid-row: 1;
}
ul.products.columns-3 li:nth-child(1) a.woocommerce-LoopProduct-link.woocommerce-loop-product__link{
     float: left;
}
ul.products.columns-3 li:nth-child(2){
     grid-column: 1 / 3;
     grid-row: 2;
}
ul.products.columns-3 li:nth-child(2) a.woocommerce-LoopProduct-link.woocommerce-loop-product__link{
     float: left;
}
ul.products.columns-3 li:nth-child(3){
     grid-column: 2 / 4;
     grid-row: 2;
}
ul.products.columns-3 li:nth-child(3) a.woocommerce-LoopProduct-link.woocommerce-loop-product__link{
     float: right;
}
```

I am open to any other methods though